# Arrays inside an Array

Tags: laravel

I want to insert data in array in this format.

```
day1[
  screen1 [  ]
  screen2 [  ]
]
day1[
   screen1 [  ]
   screen2 [  ]
]
```

So far i had tried.

```
  for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
        $date = Carbon::now()->addDays($i)->format('Y-m-d');
        $a = strtotime($date);
        $days[]=date('l',$a);
        $screen = screen::pluck('id')->toArray();
        for($j=0;$j<count($screen);$j++){
             $showTime[] =ScheduledMovie::Where('movie_id',$id)->Where('show_date',$date)->Where('show_day',$days[$i])->where('screen_id',$screen[$j])->pluck('show_time_start')->toArray();
        }
    }
```

The table used are schedule_table, Movie_table, and screen_table. The Movie table and schedule table has one to many relation. My target is to extract the show time of particular day of particular screen  from the schedule table. So far i am able to extract the show time of particular day.

Comment: Please share response what you are getting in $showTime[] array for better clarification.

Comment: array:14 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    0 => "06:00 AM"
    1 => "06:00 AM"
    2 => "10:00 AM"
    3 => "10:00 AM"
    4 => "12:10 PM"
    5 => "12:10 PM"
    6 => "02:20 PM"
    7 => "02:20 PM"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [▶]
  2 => array:8 [▶]
  3 => array:8 [▶]
  4 => array:8 [▶]
  5 => array:8 [▶]
  6 => array:8 [▶]
  7 => array:8 [▶]
  8 => array:8 [▶]
  9 => array:8 [▶]
  10 => array:8 [▶]
  11 => array:8 [▶]
  12 => array:8 [▶]
  13 => array:8 [▶]
]

Comment: You want to array should be on key like the parent array should be on key day1, day2....and child array should be on key screen1, screen2...?

Comment: That is exactly what i want.

Comment: I've answered. Please check and let me know if it is work for you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dayScreenArr = [];
for($i=0;$i<7;$i++){
    $date = Carbon::now()->addDays($i)->format('Y-m-d');
    $a = strtotime($date);
    $days[]=date('l',$a);
    $dayScreenArr[$i]['day'.$i][] = $days;
    $screen = screen::pluck('id')->toArray();
    for($j=0;$j<count($screen);$j++){
         $showTime[] =ScheduledMovie::Where('movie_id',$id)->Where('show_date',$date)->Where('show_day',$days[$i])->where('screen_id',$screen[$j])->pluck('show_time_start')->toArray();
         $dayScreenArr[$i]['day'.$i]['screen'.$i][] = $showTime;
    }
}
/* check this */
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dayScreenArr);
```